# Smallest 'install footprint' for Visual Studio 2017 - C++ core language & standard library

Tags: c++, installation, visual-studio-2017, footprint

As VS2015 insisted on a bloated install(sql servers & other such nonsense), I was glad to see VS2017 trumpet a more precise install menu.

However, I'm unable to build any of my basic projects by just installing "Visual Studio C++ core features".

What are the minimum "Individual components" required to build projects(on Win7) which implement the C++ core language & standard library?

[image]

Comment: In Workkloads I have "Desktop development with c++" checked and all other workloads unchecked.

Comment: The trouble with "Desktop development with c++" is that it includes the following components: 'SQL server express'  'SQL server native' 'C# and VB compilers' 'win 8.1' tools 'ATL' 'win10 sdk' etc etc